# Triangle wave to sine wave conversion: no output

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, analog

I am trying to replicate the following waveshaping schematic:

[image]

I've tested my version in LTspice and it seems to work fine (I've tried to make use of the one unused op-amp and created an inverse signal to feed into the base of the second resistor):

[image]

[image]

The actual assembled schematic uses different transistors that are equivalent to the 2SС544:

[image]

[image]

Here are the signals that I measured with an oscilloscope at the marked points:

**1:**
[image]

**2:**
[image]

**3:**
[image]

The op-amp is producing a constant -10.5 V (negative rail is 12 V). Adjusting Sine Symmetry pot does not affect the output. I've even tried to desolder R58 to remove inverse input for the second transistor, but the output stays constant all the same.

Could somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong with this schematic? Perhaps I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Quote: "I've tried to make use of the one unused op-amp and created an inverse signal to feed into the base of the second resistor". Ivan D, - may I ask you: WHY? Why did you not try the original circuit?

Comment: @LvW I was reading this [article](https://electrosome.com/differential-amplifier-transistors/) and thought that inverted input might reduce noise. Since I had one unused op-amp in my design available - it was not hard to put this modification into my circuit. This was probably unnecessary - but it worked in LTSpice. However, as I mention - removing R58 - and turning this circuit into the original design - did not solve the problem.

Comment: Question: Are you aware that the triangle amplitude (at the base) must not be larger than some tenth of millivolts only?

Comment: @LvW the original design had 10Vp-p input that gets scaled down by 100k and 2k2 network to ~ 215mVp-p at the base of transistor. Additionally I've tested the circuit in LTspice and it produced the desired output shape with specified resistor values.

Comment: Some years ago I have tested the quality of triangle-to-sinewave conversion with following results (Diff voltage Vd, peak values) for (70, 80, 90, 120, 160) mV: 3%, 1.3%, 2%, 3.8%, 7.5%)THD. Best values: Vd=80mV peak. However, the test was made for the "pure" diff. amplifier without R23, R24, R25 (your circuit diagram).

Comment: Note that you should check the slew-rate of the op-amp which limits the high frequency produced ...

Comment: @Antonio51 The tested input is ~ 420Hz. TL084 should easily handle such a signal.

Comment: Ok. Did not specify (?) frequency input. I tested at 1 kHz... Will try higher.

Comment: @Antonio51 I am sorry I did not specify it explicitly in text - It is visible on my oscilloscope captures.

Comment: No worries. Right. I did not "see" it, just waveforms. Tested OK until 200 kHz with 2 different BJT 1x 2N3904 and 1x 2N2222 (just use pot R6, first schematic, for "symmetry").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a negative supply to bias the transistors into operation. Returning R32 to ground won't do.

Comment: Yes - of course. But I can see such a negative supply in the LTC-schematic.

Comment: Indeed I seems that it was a mistake while I was redrawing schematic from LTSpice. I've connected R32 to -10V supply and also installed closely matched transistors with hFE=136 and 137 respectively. [This](https://ibb.co/WK13Q1G) is a current output from the audio jack which is installed after C10 and 1k resistor on the other board. Weirdly the op-amp output at **4** is noisy and is close to -9V and does not resemble this shape - although it may be limitation of my oscilloscope since it can't lock to the frequency.

Comment: This output was obtained while sine symmetry trimpot is rotated to the rightmost position. Otherwise voltage at **4** stays constantly at -10.5V

Comment: The mentioned output looks quite similar in shape to what simulation shows with sine symmetry pot turned all the way to one side: [capture](https://ibb.co/P6mLzQ5). However in the real circuit there is a huge amount of negative offset at the output of op-amp. I am not sure what's causing it.

Comment: @LvW I've tried installing yet another set of transistors now matching their Vbe - still there is huge negative voltage on the op-amp output that prevents correct signal formation there (at least that's what I think is happening). I've checked all the values of placed components and they are the same as on the schematic. Still I am not sure where this negative voltage originates from. I will try removing  connections to transistors altogether and see if output from U4:C together with  R46, R43, R48 and R39 forms op-amp differential amplifier with 0V output.

Comment: And what about R59? Did you "play" with this component? Is it really necessary? For which purpose?

Comment: @LvW, after removing both transistors my output from the op-amp stayed close to negative rail - probably something was wrong with my PCB traces - and upon probing each trace that was connected to the op-amp I've noticed that R39 and R43 were not connected to anything. I probably damaged the trace during earlier rework. Anyway, after connecting these resistors with a wire back to the op-amp and installing transistors back my output looks like [this](https://ibb.co/KLgByPf). This is already close enough to desired output for my application. Increasing R60 and R58 might make it more sine-like.

Comment: I am sure - when you reduce the triangle amplitude the THD would be much smaller.